# store JSON data from Fetch in a variable outside scope of fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch

Hope all is well.
Using node w fetch &
trying to 'Get' the contents of a JSON file to be used in other functions in my script & possibly other scripts. Until now, i can only use them inside the fetch scope which is not optimal. pretty new to this but been workin on it for a couple days, read/watched a ton of tutorials, & searched here as well w no luck:-(
for instance i'd like to do something like:

```
fetch (json){ }

let thePrice = data.price;

let theAmntSold = data.price;
```

....then later in script be able to use data.price & theAmntSold ie

```
totalAmntEarned(thePrice, theAmntSold) {
return thePrice * theAmntSold;
}
```

here is the latest I came up with and no luck

```
let theSystem, themaxPrice,
theblockPrices = [],
mainObj = {};

let showObj = function() {
//asyncronous so we need to set up for loop in a function
for (let prop in mainObj) {
    console.log(prop);
    console.log(mainObj[prop]);
}

};


fetch(URL, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Authorization: AUTH_KEY
    }

}).then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
}) //assign variables below
.then(function(data) {
    showObj();
    let theblockPrices = data.blockPrices;
    
    console.log(data.maxPrice);
    console.log(theblockPrices[0]);
    });
```

so basically, i'd like to be able to use 'theblockPrices' in another function or variable. Also, when i call the showObj() inside the fetch block, I get no output in the console. Any tips would be amazing!

thanks

Comment: welcome to async code. Thats just how it works. You gotta wait until its there, either by callback, .then or await.

Comment: That would require time travel. By the time the data is available, your "outer scope" has already finished what it needed to do and returned. Just use the promise instead, .then can be called repeatedly on a given promise to get the same data out of it

Comment: Cmon donnie lol, why'd you close this? I was writing an answer.

Comment: @DanZuzevich there's a few dozen existing questions revolving around this that you could apply your answer to (such as one dupe target)

Comment: @DanZuzevich, Donnie didn't close this, and you shouldn't be writing an answer.

Comment: ok. I'll check out some of ur references. would be cool to open it up for like an hour or so no? 
as I said, i tried so many of the examples i found here on stackoverflow & nothing was working. thanks

Comment: @TheFool thanks, did a few variations of async no luck. also, i used the .then in this one. appreciate the reply

Comment: @KevinB - thanks. will try again. Isn't the .then supposed to take care of that tho?

Comment: `then` is called when the data is available and lets you do stuff with it *then* (hence the name). It can't be used to send the data back in time so it was available when you previously called another function while waiting for the asynchronous code to resolve.

Comment: @Quentin - ok. makes sense. thanks for the help. will give it a shot